# Debuging of jar contents in Intellij Idea

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have a non-trivial maven build which produces a jar fille and I want Itellij Idea to pick up maven's output and then launch the jar but IDE doesn't allow me to specify a jar to use in 'Application' launch configuration. Please suggest a way to configure project this way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new dummy module with this jar added to its [Dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html) and attach sources to the library, then you can debug it by specifying the main class in the Run configuration. The module itself may not contain sources or other content roots.

Comment: Is it possible to do without creating a new module, but with a new configuration for an already existing module?

Comment: No, as it will contain the classes from this module classpath, not only the jar that you want to debug.